# Javascript data type for storing large number of elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a code for a snake and ladders logic (without the ui) in JavaScript. I need to scale it to 10,000 snakes and ladders. I am new to JavaScript. I have managed to do this for 5 snakes and 5 ladders with 2 players using arrays. But I'm not sure if arrays will be efficient for 10000 elements development and maintenance wise. What should I use instead?

```
var ladderTop = [55, 40];
var ladderBottom = [35, 25];
```

The arrays I'm using is similar to this.
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/nightshade235/pen/oojabm

Also, suppose I wanted to change the 32nd  element out of 10,000 elements, would arrays still be efficient?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: premature optimization?

Comment: The codepen link: https://codepen.io/nightshade235/pen/oojabm

Comment: nothing more convenient than arrays for changing element at specific index

Comment: @overloading I don't know what premature optimization is.

Comment: @Slai, that's what I thought, but my guide seemed adamant on finding a better way out.

Comment: maybe your guide thinks that for example combining the arrays might be more "efficient" `var ladder = [ [ 55, 35 ], [ 40, 25] ]`, but I don't think it will be. It's hard to guess without more context.

Comment: @Slai I think you are right, since it is easier to change both the top and bottom of a ladder at once this way. But single dimension array is faster I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your guide might be suggesting combining the arrays. For example:

```js
var data = [ { ladder: { Top: 55, Bottom: 35 }, snake: { Top: 22, Bottom:  8 } }, 
             { ladder: { Top: 40, Bottom: 25 }, snake: { Top: 60, Bottom: 43 } } ]

console.log( data[1].snake.Top )
```

Combining the arrays is definitely not more efficient, because it will take a bit more time to parse and will create more objects, but might be subjectively easier to maintain if the project gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm not sure if arrays will be efficient for 10000 elements development and maintenance wise. What should I use instead?

But somehow you're sure that you should use something else?

There's nothing wrong with *huge* arrays in javascript

```js
console.time ('add 1 million items')
console.log (
  Array.from (Array (1e6), (_,x) => x)
    .reduce ((x,y) => x + y, 0))
console.timeEnd ('add 1 million items') 
// 499999500000
// add 1 million items: 225ms
```

Scale it to 10M with no exponential cost

```js
console.time ('add 10 million items')
console.log (
  Array.from (Array (1e7), (_,x) => x)
    .reduce ((x,y) => x + y, 0))
console.timeEnd ('add 10 million items') 
// 49999995000000
// add 10 million items: 2537.070 ms
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I should use anything else, but my guide asked me to think on how convenient it would be to change the 32nd element for example out of 10,000 elements.

Comment: @Nightshade How convenient? It's directly accessible. Did you mean how efficient?